# How to use proxy_redirect for docker network aliases in nginx?

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy, docker-networking

I'm building a docker web project. There are, for example, two containers, called `A` and `B`. I use `A` for the main server, which listens `80` port and deals with static pages. The url path `/api` is proxied to the backend server `B`. I write the config file like this:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location ~* ^/api/?(.*)$ {
        rewrite ^/api/?(.*)$ /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://api;
        proxy_redirect http://api/ /api/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

The `rewrite` line makes sure that `/api/test` is redirected to `/test` on `B`.

I add the `proxy_direct` line because when I access `/api/test`, the backend server will raise a `307` temporary redirection. However, since the proxy removes the `/api` prefix, the redirection does not perform well.

The expected result should be: when the backend server redirects `/test` to `/test/`, the main server modifys the redirection to `/api/test/`.

However, the code above does not work. I think the problem might be that `api` is the docker network alias for `B`, not the original host name. Thus the redirection can not be matched by the alias.

I've tried to replace `http://api/` with `$proxy_host`, but the problem still remains.